# Do a file removal by “git revert” is a bug?

Tags: git, shell

To reproduce the behavior that looks like a bug, let's do the following:

Creating a temporary directory:

```
$ mkdir tmp
$ cd tmp
```

Creating some text file:

```
$ echo "some text" > tmp.txt
```

Initializing empty Git repository:

```
$ git init
```

Staging `tmp.txt`:

```
$ git add tmp.txt
```

Recording the working tree changes to the repository:

```
$ git commit
```

Checking changes to the repository:

```
$ git log --oneline
```

833f4b3 (HEAD -> master) Reproducing a revert bug: Add tmp.txt

Reverting initial commit:

```
$ git revert 833f4b3

$ ls -al  # Shows that tmp.txt was deleted
```

After that, it would be more logical to expect that `git revert` leaves `tmp.txt` only staged but not delete it from the working tree. Because the `tmp.txt` had existed before the initial commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git doesn't care about when the file was created. It cares about what's on the revision. On the revision, the file was created with a certain content... then you ask to revert (content is still the same), it deletes the file.

To provide some context:
when git creates a revision, it *doesn't* save a lot of information about a file (when it's file)... besides the content... and a few permissions flag. So, on that very first revision, you create a revision object, the revision object would point to a tree object, the root directory information.... with the subdirectories and files pressent on that directory. In your case, on the root directory tree object you would see *yet* another object, the file we are talking about, which point to a blob object (the file content itself). So, what git does to know what it will revert is to compare with the previous revision of the one you want to revert. The previous revision does not exist, so git understands that you want to take back the file as a whole because previous to this revision the file didn't exist.... after the revision, the file does exist and has some content. If you want to revert it, file has to go away if content matches.... if you had changed the content (on a second revision, for example) and then you tried to revert the first revision, you would see a tree conflict... and a content conflict?  Not sure about the content conflict. The tree conflict kicks in because git won't try to delete the file if content does not match what was on the revision where it was added on a revert operation.

Comment: It's not clear enough what certain file content means. The file was created when the git repository hadn't been created yet.

Comment: ??? It does not matter. To git, on that revision you _creted the file_ and added the content. Let me put it this way: if you were git, what would you save on that first revision? Added content? On a file that is not present on the _non existing_ revision? Let me put a little bit about the way that git works in the response so you get some context.

Comment: I got it. After 

`$ git add tmp.txt`

, this file has become tracked and staged, but not a part of the working tree or the `.git directory` yet. After 

`$ git commit 833f4b3`

`tmp.txt` had become a part of the `.git directory` or working tree. And after 

`$ git revert 833f4b3`

`git` back working directory accordingly to the state of the `.git directory` before `git commit`. Before `git commit` working tree was without `tmp.txt`. So the file has to be deleted.

Comment: I'm glad you got the idea. However, technically: not exactly. As soon as you add an object to the staging area, git put those objects (files, directories) inside its DB. Then git will create a different kind of object, a revision, when you commit.